# JMeter parametrization $URL

Tags: jmeter

I have problem with set parametrize `$url` variable in Jmeter.
I must set parametrize because I will run my project test in three other URL addresses, because application is deployed for 3 others such as production, development and I also would like testing in local.

I have the following CSV file:

```
protocol                        
                $url
    ${dev}  http://10.200.XXX.XX/{$url}
    ${trial}    trial.mycompany.io{$url}
    ${product}  product.mycompany.io{$url}
```

How can I set this in JMeter, set parametrization my URL variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, moreover my expectation is that you shouldn't have JMeter variables reference in form of `${variable}` in the CSV file, only "plain" data should go there.

With regards to running test on different servers I would go for creating 3 separate CSV files, i.e.

1. `dev.csv` with the following contents:

   protocol,host
      http,10.200.XXX.XX/
2. `trial.csv` with the following contents

   protocol,host
      https,trial.mycompany.io
3. `product.csv` with the following contents

   protocol,host
      https,product.mycompany.io

Once done you can add a [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and set it up like:

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

And finally add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) to your Test Plan to read the values from the relevant CSV file:

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]

---

So when you run JMeter without any parameters it will pick up `dev.csv` file and will go to `10.200.XXX.XX` host

If you run JMeter like:

```
jmeter -Jenvironment=trial
```

it will pick up `trial.csv` and will go to `trial.mycompany.io` host

If you run JMeter like:

```
jmeter -Jenvironment=product
```

it will pick up `product.csv` and will go to `product.mycompany.io.` host

More information:

- [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)